# Trouble booting after replacing CMOS battery

Tags: boot, motherboard, cmos

After replacing my CMOS battery today, I initially got the expected BIOS warning that the CMOS settings are wrong in that the time was off. After I set the time, I had the BIOS save the updated settings, which usually leads to a reboot. Unfortunately, not only did it not reboot, my screen came up empty altogether, while the computer whistled on merrily as if it was working fine.

I've since noticed that if I take the CMOS battery out and then put it back in again, I'm back at the "CMOS time wrong" screen. Basically, any reboot will get me back to black-screen-but-computer-whizzing mode, and reseating the CMOS battery gets me back to the "CMOS time wrong" screen.

I've currently taken out the CMOS battery to stay out over night since I read somewhere that it may take more than the 20 seconds I left it out previously to restore all settings, but other than that I'm at my wit's end. Any and all help is appreaciated.

Comment: @Psycogeek Will try!

Comment: @Psycogeek I'm not entirely sure why, but just fiddling around going through BIOS settings without actually changing anything relevant let me boot consistently to a (pooched) Windows. I was able to reinstall and get the machine running again. If you like, please post your comment as an answer so I can give you credit!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are often settings made to the bios/uefi that are off from the defaults that can be critical to booting. It is good to write down settings prior to resetting or flashing a bios. Removing the battery resets everything to defaults, any of the needed changes would have to be remade.

This can be things like:
The  Boot Order
Default IDE RAID AHCI settings for the SATA controller , which can cause windows systems to crash on boot when the OS driver is not matching.
  Compatability boot modes for mbr booting, (if it was a UEFI ,mbr booting before).
 Video card priority, even onboard or on-die video disabled (usually not default).
Shared memory ammounts for video devices.

Less likely to cause issues but no less important to speed:
 Remapped or extended memory settings (64bit) Without the remap the memory ammount can be less than installed.
Lower settings for memory divisor, clock rate, bus speed and even bus lane widths, and gen speeds (gen 1,2,3 for PCI-e).

Other items, past booting:
 Even the clock setting itself, which most people will adjust quick, can be overly important. These "security" things often will not work correct when the time is off.

Get back into the bios and set things to the best of your ability, follow online guides, learn a bit about your bios options. Eventually write down what the settings are , and forget where you put it, when needed again.